# Promise - Resolving after multiple events

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using a promise to asynchronously connect to an API. The API emits two events: `connected` and `socketConnected`.

As per my `connect()` function, I would like to wait for both of those events to fire.

```
connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    this._client.on('connected', resolve);
    this._client.on('socketConnected', resolve);
    setTimeout(reject, 5000);
  }
}
```

However, you can only resolve once, and I want both events to fire before the promise resolves. How can I set this up so that it behaves that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to create *two* promises, one for each event, and when both resolve - when the `Promise.all` resolves - you can resolve the promise that `connect` returns:

```
connect() {
  return new Promise((resolveAll, rejectAll) => {
    Promise.all([
      new Promise(res1 => this._client.on('connected', res1)),
      new Promise(res2 => this._client.on('socketConnected', res2))
    ]).then(resolveAll);
    setTimeout(rejectAll, 5000);
  });
}
```

You might also clear the timeout when the `Promise.all` resolves, if you want garbage collection to occur as soon as possible:

```
connect() {
  return new Promise((resolveAll, rejectAll) => {
    const rejectTimeout = setTimeout(rejectAll, 5000);
    Promise.all([
      new Promise(res1 => this._client.on('connected', res1)),
      new Promise(res2 => this._client.on('socketConnected', res2))
    ]).then(() => {
      clearTimeout(rejectTimeout);
      resolveAll();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better if you stopped the timer when/if both events occur?  Then, you don't keep a timer running that is going to be ignored and you allow objects to be GCed immediately rather than only when the timer goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of *reusable* code - if you find yourself wanting to timeout a Promise, then why not write a function to do so

```
const promiseTimeout = (promise, timeout) => {
    let timer;
    return Promise.race([
        promise, 
        new Promise((_, reject) => (timer = setTimeout(reject, timeout, promiseTimeout.symbol)))
    ])
    .then(result => (clearTimeout(timer), result));
};
promiseTimeout.symbol = Symbol('timeout');
```

Now, you can use that anywhere you need to set a time limit for a promise

In this case, as already observed, you'll need **two** promises for your logic, wrapped in a Promise.all, that get's you one promise that resolves when both promises resolve

i.e.

```
const promise = Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => this._client.on('connected', resolve)),
    new Promise(resolve => this._client.on('socketConnected', resolve))
]);
```

now, combining these two code snippets

```
const promiseTimeout = (promise, timeout) => {
    let timer;
    return Promise.race([
        promise, 
        new Promise((_, reject) => (timer = setTimeout(reject, timeout, promiseTimeout.symbol)))
    ])
    .then(result => (clearTimeout(timer), result));
};
promiseTimeout.symbol = Symbol('timeout');

function connect() {
    const promise = Promise.all([
        new Promise(resolve => this._client.on('connected', resolve)),
        new Promise(resolve => this._client.on('socketConnected', resolve))
    ]);
    return promiseTimeout(promise, 5000);
}

// if connect rejects with reason promiseTimeout.symbol, you can be sure it was because of the timeout
```

Though, the other answer is better in this case, I only offer this answer in case you do find yourself wanting to set a time limit on a promise resolution

Comment: You reusable timeout doesn't reject with any identifying error such that the user would know it was a timeout that caused it to reject.  The concept is good, but the implementation falling a bit short.

Comment: simple code example was too simple :p based on OP's simple code - fixed it just for you, @jfriend00 :p (it was a very valid point you made) - the same criticism could be made of the accepted answer :p

Comment: I upvoted, but if you want to follow convention to reject with an Error object, this code does not make that easy.  The caller has to precreate an error object that may never be used when they call `promiseTimeout()`.

Comment: true, it has failings I've not considered